# access mail content from shared Mailbox SubFolders using Python

Tags: python

have got a code to access mail content from folders other than Inbox folder. my requirement is to access a shared mailbox and within that a subfolder of a folder other than Inbox of shared mailbox.

please provide any solution.

below is my code:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Parent.Folders("Group Folders - HF")

# inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                    # any other folder
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body
print (body_content)
```

Comment: 'Group Folders - HF' is a sub folder within 'Clients' folder and 'Clients' folder is in shared mailbox named 'mumbai@xyz.com'